# Use an android player with download button when clicking mp3 links on WebView

Tags: android, webview

I'm new to this site and new to android programming and I need help. I have a webview where the webpage loaded has particular links and those links are mp3 playable files. What code(s) should I use to make it play(stream) and/or download within my android app instead of opening up browsers to play it? Thanks!

EDIT:
I have tried this:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

which now plays the mp3 links but it only allows me to play and pause the audio file, and I'm stuck right now, is there a way for me to add something like a download button also a seek bar. Still, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Show your source code

Comment: haven't tried anything yet, I just managed to make the webview work.

Comment: Then I vote to close your question. First do some work on your own and then ask questions when you stuck

Answer (score 0):

You want to play audio? If it is complex page with HTML5 content, you can use crosswalk library and XWalkView instead of WebView. But this library will strongly increase your apk size.

To download file go through this tutorial:

http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2013/11/download-file-videoaudiotext-through.html

Comment: Hi thanks for your awesome answer. I tried to simulate the codes in the link that you've given through a new project but Im having an error. It says:

'Cannot resolve symbol DownloadWebView'

tried looking anywhere else for its fix but I found nothing.